# Assessing variabililty of count data

Tags: variance, count-data, interval-censoring

I have count data where I'm counting the number of dots per cell in each individual, there at 5 bins I'm using to tally my scores:

- Number of cells that are negative (i.e. no dots)
- Number of cells containing 1-3 dots
- Number of cells containing 4-6 dots
- Number of cells containing 7-9 dots
- Number of cells containing 10+ dots

I want to assess the variability seen within each individual. Currently I have been able to achieve a SD but not sure the method I have used is sound. 
I am using a weighted mean, hopefully my equations make sense (I'm not a mathematician so apologizes - please correct me)

$\overline{x} = n_{negdot}\times0 + n_{1:3dots}\times1 + n_{3:6dots}\times2 + n_{7:9dots}\times3 + n_{10dots}\times4$

And then can do a variance, SD and CV from that, the equation for the variance is below, obviously the SD and CV are easy to work out from there.

$\sigma = \left ( n_{negdots}\times\left ( 0-\overline{x} \right )^2 \right  ) +\left ( n_{1:3dots}\times\left ( 0-\overline{x} \right )^2 \right  ) +\left ( n_{4:6dots}\times\left ( 0-\overline{x} \right )^2 \right  )+\left ( n_{7:9dots}\times\left ( 0-\overline{x} \right )^2 \right  )+\left ( n_{10dots}\times\left ( 0-\overline{x} \right )^2 \right  )$

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to handle count data, and whether my approach is appropriate

Comment: To clarify: each individual has a number of cells associated with it, and the number of dots per cell can vary. Is this a correct description of your data?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: In effect, you have interval-censored count data, see [tag:interval-censoring].